# Azure Error: AuthorizationFailed

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk-python

I am using Azure SDK for python to create resource using python script.After giving the required credentials like CLIENT_ID,TENANT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,SUBSCRIPTION_ID..It throws a error message like

> "msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: 
>   Azure Error: AuthorizationFailed
>   Message: The client 'CLIENT_ID' with object id 'OBJECT_ID' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope ''."
>
> > (I am using azure in free trial type of subscription)

Comment: Make sure you assign the right role for the service principal to manage the resources necessary. You can go to any subscription/resource group/resource -> *Access control (IAM)* to do this.

Comment: Yep, as @juunas  said, it should be caused you didn't assign role to your sp via IAM. Go to azure portal > subscription > IAM > Add > choose your sp and assign one necessary role to it. Also please give us feedback if you have any process or questions on it.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a service principal(SP) associated with the application. Also, to assign a role to SP you need to be an 'owner' or the Azure portal does not show you that option if you are a 'contributor' in UI.